# validation rule on quote object

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Could someone help me how to create a validation rule that will fulfill the following requirement: When Quote name contains prefix "H", the opportunity owner should not be changeable.
I tried with contains and is changed, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: VRs fire on the object being changed and only have access to the target object and lookup object fields; So, DML on Opportunity can look at Oppo field and any lookups on Oppo. Quote is a child of Oppo

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't achieve this using the Validation rule. You have to use a trigger for this. While changing opportunity owner, you need to check if there is any quote which is associated with this opportunity which has "H" as a prefix. To get the related quotes of the opportunity, you can use trigger and add prevent owner change if there is any quote record is available where the prefix is "H".

Comment: Thank you very much for your support